# German handwriting recognition

Tags: handwriting

I am trying to read the handwriting on this archive record of a German airman who was killed in action during WW2.

I know that the airman was born in Bergneustadt and I think the first part is:

???? Eltern: Bergneustadt |

I cannot read the second part which I think is the street address of his parents, followed by the number 33, which I assume is the house number.

Is anyone able to read the street name? The record is from 1941, so the street may longer exist.

[image]

Comment: Ich stimme für Schließung, denn wir sollten keinen Handschriftenentzifferungsservice o.ä. (Grabsteine, ...) anbieten. Wird immer wieder gefragt und macht vielen Spaß, das zu beantworten, aber der Lerneffekt für den nächsten mit einer ähnlichen Frage ist Null. Absolut Zero. Es wird als reine Dienstleistung nachgefragt und konsumiert.

Comment: while this is latin handwriting, the 'd' is written in sütterlin, isnt it?

Comment: See: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/sind-fragen-%c3%bcber-die-entschl%c3%bcsselung-von-schriften-auch-handschriften-on-topic and https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/579/are-questions-on-reading-of-old-handwritings-on-topic. People in favour of closing such questions appear to be a minority there.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like:

> Bergneustadt/Rhld. (abbr. for *Rheinland*), Lörracherstr. 33

to me.

Comment: Vor "Eltern" könnte **H. A. :** stehen

Comment: @PaulFrost Likely „Heimatadresse“

Comment: There is no *Lörracher Straße* in the [street directory](https://digitale-sammlungen.ulb.uni-bonn.de/periodical/pageview/5076733?query=Stra%C3%9Fenverzeichnis) of Bergneustadt from 1973.